# Getting Carmen-Rails Subregion select to work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have been working on getting the Carmen-rails demo to work in my application to no avail. I know the coffeescript is working as I can get things to work by using document.ready. The problem at this point from what I can tell is that when the Country is changed the State does not update at all. Here is what I have.

In my form which is using simple_form:

```
%h3 Country
= f.input :country, priority: %w(US CA IL), input_html: {id: "country_select"}, prompt: 'Please select a country'
= render partial: 'subregion_select', locals: {parent_region: f.object.country}
```

_subregion_select partial:

```
#customer_state_code_wrapper
  - parent_region ||= params[:parent_region]
  - logger.info("Parent region is #{parent_region}")
  - country = Carmen::Country.coded(parent_region) unless parent_region.nil?
  - if country.nil?
    %em Please select a country above
  - elsif country.subregions?
    = subregion_select(:customer, :state, parent_region)
  - else
    = text_field(:customer, :state)
```

customer.js.coffee

```
$ ->
  $('select#country_select').change (event) ->
    alert "Blah"
    select_wrapper = $('#customer_state_code_wrapper')
    $('select', select_wrapper).attr('readonly', true)
    country_code = $(this).val()
    url = "/customers/subregion_options?parent_region=#{country_code}"
    select_wrapper.load(url)
```

When I click on the country select box and change the value nothing happens not even the alert is triggered. I have the proper id for the select box as it shows to be:

```
<select class="country optional" id="country_select" name="customer[offices_attributes]
```

I see no errors in the console for the java and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

For better formatting when I look at the compiled JS file in the console it shows the following:

```
(function() {
  $(function() {
    return $('select#country_select').change(function(event) {
      var country_code, select_wrapper, url;
      alert("Blah");
      select_wrapper = $('#customer_state_code_wrapper');
      $('select', select_wrapper).attr('readonly', true);
      country_code = $(this).val();
      url = "/customers/subregion_options?parent_region=" + country_code;
      return select_wrapper.load(url);
    });
  });
}).call(this);
```

After looking further I think the problem may be that this form is rendered from a partial that is loaded via simple_nested_form via:

`= f.fields_for :offices do |o|
 = render :partial => 'offices', :locals => {:o => o}
= f.link_to_add image_tag("layout_add.png") + " Add Another Office", :offices`

So I think when the javascript is loaded there is nothing present for it to attach to. When I click the link_to_add, which loads the form then run the:

```
$('select#country_select').change ->
  alert "blah"
```

via the console it works as it should. So how do I get the script to load after someone clicks the link_to_add which displays the form?

Comment: what is the result if you evaluate in the web console: `$('select#country_select')` once that page is loaded?

Comment: I'm using Chrome and when I take a look at the compiled Javascript file the output is as follows:

`(function() {
  $(function() {
    return $('select#country_select').change(function(event) {
      var country_code, select_wrapper, url;
      alert("Blah");
      select_wrapper = $('#customer_state_code_wrapper');
      $('select', select_wrapper).attr('readonly', true);
      country_code = $(this).val();
      url = "/customers/subregion_options?parent_region=" + country_code;
      return select_wrapper.load(url);
    });
  });

}).call(this);`

I'm not sure how to evaluate the JS

Comment: If I type `$('select#country_select')` in the console it returns:

`<select class="country optional" id="country_select" name="customer[offices_attributes][1410358723774][country]"><option value="">Please select a country</option>`

This also includes all of the elements of the select box but I left them out due to the length.

Comment: delete all the code inside the select event except for your alert and see if it will alert then.

Comment: I cleaned everything out except the alert and still nothing happens.

Comment: Added more details above.

Comment: I fixed your coffeescript indentation, but I dont see how this form partial is being loaded asynchronously. it appears to me to be rendered on the server which means your html would be available for jquery on ready.

Comment: Strange.. I modified the controller to load an instance of the nested form when the page loads and now the javascript works correctly but any additional nested form i add it does not work for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jed's last comment led me to figuring the problem out. I modified the js.coffee to watch for change on the select box which fires the event properly.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Can you post your solution?

Comment: Basically my form was nested inside of the main form with "nested_attributes_for" function. What I ended up having to do was to separate it out in its own page and not use the "nested_attributes_for" in the main form. This fixed the problem.